# Finding a folder that has the same name using Linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, path, directory

I have this function that you pass a path to a directory that contains folders name for example like UPDATE_20162406_x.x.x (the version) the files will always have the same beggining but the date and the version will be different, what I need now is to pass a path to the UPDATE_someDATE_x.x.x to a function that checks if there is any other folder with the same version, this is the query I have that needs to be changed:

```
 public string NewestUpdate(string Directoria)
        {
            string caminho = "";
            Version version = null;
            var lastVersion = new DirectoryInfo(Directoria).EnumerateDirectories()
            .Where(d => d.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("update_"))
        .Select(d => new { Directory = d, Token = d.Name.Split('_') })
        .Where(x => x.Token.Length == 3 && Version.TryParse(x.Token[2], out version))
        .Select(x => new { x.Directory, Date = x.Token[1], Version = version })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
        .FirstOrDefault();
            if (lastVersion != null)
            {

                caminho = lastVersion.Directory.FullName.ToString();
                Global.LatestVersion = lastVersion.Version.ToString();
            }

            return caminho;

        }
```

I don't know linq almost anything and Im not being able to write the proper query to do this.
Any help is apreciated. thank you

Comment: Have you tried using the `Directory.GetDirectories(path)` method? This returns a `string[]` of all directories in your specified path. You can then do a `.Where(x => x.StartsWith("UPDATE_"))` to get a collection back of those folders :) Reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your code gets the latest version perfectly . So ? You want to pass a version number to this method and check if you have another folder with the same version ?

Comment: @user3185569 I will do a new function for that but yes it's exactly that. and if it exists I just return true

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName check answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static bool NewestUpdate(string Directoria, Version queryVersion)
{
    Version version = null;
    var foundFolder = (from d in new DirectoryInfo(Directoria).EnumerateDirectories()
                        where d.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("update_")
                        let token = d.Name.Split('_')
                        let vers = token.Length == 3 && Version.TryParse(token[2], out version) ? version : null
                        where vers == queryVersion
                        select d).FirstOrDefault();

    string directory = foundFolder?.FullName;

    return foundFolder != null;
}
```

Comment: that seems fine, how can I get the path of the folder with the same version? damn I need to leatn linq :\

Comment: thx man I will be testing it out. would you be kind to recommend some Linq tutorials?

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName please accept this answer. And here is good tutorial from Microsoft: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b